# How to build SSIS package to UPSERT/DELETE data from Salesforce to SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, salesforce, etl, cozyroc

I need to pull data from Salesforce to a SQL Server 2017 instance (one way) using SSIS+ (third party - CozyRock).

Now the issue is to retrieve the data and not duplicate it in the SQL Server database?

I was wondering also if I can build a button on Salesforce that make a stored procedure or job to run this SSIS package, is this possible?

I've checked [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/adding-rows-in-incremental-loads-level-3-of-the-stairway-to-integration-services) from Andy Leonard post but haven't gotten the solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer.

In order to achieve this, we need a field to track the last time a record was updated and the following.

Step 1:

- Set Sources:

  - Source from where the data comes. Set it as Source.
  - Source where the data will be stored. Set it as a Destination.

Step 2:

- Sort Data streams by their Id field.

Step 3:

- Merge Join, Merge them using a full outer join.
- First, select the Source field and secondly the Destination fields.
- Rename the output with Source_ prefix to the source fields and Destination with Destination_ prefix.

Step 4:

- Use a conditional split to split the records by change type.
- The logic in here is, use those mandatory fields in the record (E.g. Id).
- First conditional split:

  - New Records: !ISNULL([Source_Id]) && ISNULL(Destination_ID)
  - Deleted Records: ISNULL([Source_Id]) && !ISNULL(Destination_ID)
  - Set default ouput as Existing Records.

Step 5:

- Insert New Records: use an ODBC/OLE Destination and do the corresponding set up and mapping.

Step 6:

- Update Records: use another conditional split to find which reports have been updated.
- Use this logic inside the conditional split:
  Updated Values: ([Source_Id == Destination_Id])&&(([Source_LastUpdate != Destination_LastUpdate]))
- Use a OLE Command: set the connection and build an update query in properties and map it accordingly.

Step 7:

- Delete Records: use an OLE DB Command to delete the records which Id = Destination_Id

[Related Documentation](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5082/synchronize-table-data-using-a-merge-join-in-ssis/) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can solve the duplicate issue.

1) Get only incremental data, if the table you are ingesting from salesforce have update_at timestamp, you can use that to pull only new/updated records.

2) Use MERGE instead of insert or update, it will handle the duplicates more gracefully [enter link description here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/)

yeah, you can create a button in salesforce and call a shell script , but it will be much easier to schedule the ssis job to run for every 5 mins and capture the updates from salesforce